# Packets not being captured when negotiating TLS versions with .NET SslStream

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming, wireshark

My set up is:

- I have a server listener app that only accepts TLS 1.0 connections.
- I have a client app that uses SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient to configure a secure connection
- I am using WireShark to monitor traffic between client and server

On the client machine I use the SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols registry keys to manipulate which version of TLS I want to use.  If I force the client to use TLS 1.2 I get the expected error of "The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm".  However, the only packets that get captured in WireShark are the TCP 3-way handshake.

Conversely, if I explicitly specify Tls1.2 in the call to SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient I see the Client Hello and Server Hello TLS messages in WireShark.  And of course, I see the same expected error message as above.

My question is, when I'm only using the Registry to manipulate TLS versions how come I do not see any TLS packets being sent through WireShark?  How does Windows/.NET know that the remote server does not support TLS 1.2?

Thanks

Comment: Most probably you have an error in the application that is triggered as soon as the client tries to send the Hello message and this is why you don't see the SSL packets. The message that appears is probably an error in your code that shows that message on every SSL error.

Comment: I suggest that you also enable System.NET tracing to compare.